# What is the proper way to format this txt document with csv writer and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am a newbie at writing and formatting files I only started today so please go easy on me. I have this piece of code which will create a csv file and writes a single column with header named `Vertices`. Each row in the csv would contain 64 vertices extracted from a 3d cylinder model. Each vertex will contains a group of x, y, z values. Basically I want something like this:

```
  Extracted_Vertices
0 [(3.2, 9.9, 3.4), (5.8, 4.5, 2.3), (7.5, 1.9, 2.9)...] 
1 [(2.2, 9.2, 3.4), (3.8, 9.5, 4.7), (8.5, 3.9, 5.5)...]
```

Each row will contain 64 vertices, with each vertex contains 3 values for xyz.

[Code that writes the csv file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv80F.png)

[What the csv file looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLEoM.png)

[What happens when I try to read the file in pandas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJM4a.png)

Edited: The copy and pasted code

```
with open('cylinder_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Vertices'])

        for i in range(2):
            vertices_temp = cylinder_generation()
            vertices_temp = np.round(vertices_temp,3)
            file_names.append('img_' + str(i))
            writer.writerow([*vertices_temp])
```

Pandas Code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.read_csv('cylinder_data.csv')
foo.head()
foo['Vertices'][0]
```

Edited2:

Cylinder_generation function:
This is the only code that matters from cylinder_generation, I didn't want to post this code because as you can see it's sort of irrelevant, all it does is use list comprehension to store 3 xyz values by calling Blender's own python api.

```
ob = bpy.data.objects['Cylinder'] # Select Cylinder
ob.rotation_euler = rotation_xyz # Change its rotation

verts = [vert.co for vert in ob.data.vertices]
```

If you check the 2nd image I posted the result of writing to the text document is the `writerow('img_ + str(i)')` plus all the vertices from the list comprehension.

Comment: Don't put code on external sites; just paste everything into your question. And definitely don't list code as an image! No one can copy what you've done if it's an image.

Comment: I don't understand I have edited and provided more information but I am still getting downvoted. What else do I need to fix?

Comment: Please add the actual code of how you are generating the vertices, for example the definition of the function cylinder_generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem.

```
verts = []
for vert in ob.data.vertices:
    verts.extend(vert.co)
```

I used extended instead of append which gave me a nice list of `[x1, y1, z1....x64, y64, z64]`

I also took away of the other extra useless lines

```
with open(path, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Vertices'])
    for i in range(2):
        # vertices_temp = np.round(vertices_temp,3) # REMOVED
        # file_names.append('img_' + str(i)) # REMOVED
        vertices_temp = cylinder_generation() # This contains all 64 (xyz) for the vertex
        writer.writerow([vertices_temp]) # REMOVED the *
```

Once I started to mess with the actual generated text file and its formatting I realized the exact format pandas need to display the data correctly, all I had to do now is just to recreate the formatting from my script.